# How do I detect which device was recently created by pppd?

Tags: networking, arch-linux, scripting, pppd

I'm trying to setup a VPN over SSH using PPPD (following [the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VPN_over_SSH#Using_PPP_over_SSH)). The command given is:

```
/usr/sbin/pppd updetach noauth silent nodeflate pty \
  "/usr/bin/ssh root@remote-gw /usr/sbin/pppd nodetach notty noauth"  \
  ipparam vpn 10.0.8.1:10.0.8.2
```

I have successfully managed to set it up with appropriate modifications to the above command. To connect to the internal network on the server side, I had to set up forwarding using `iptables` on the server side (blindly following [this SF post](https://serverfault.com/a/431607/229499)):

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o ppp0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I'd like to automate this. Now, `eth0` is fixed, but the `ppp0` may change (for example, someone else also has started a similar setup). How can I detect what interface was created by the `pppd` command on the server side? <strike>Parse `dmesg`</strike>? Diff the output of `ip -o a`? Can I get `pppd` to report it to me?

- Client is an up-to-date Arch Linux
- Server is an up-to-date Ubuntu 14.04

---

`dmesg` seems to be useless:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i ppp
[    0.803033] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[135747.442807] PPP BSD Compression module registered
[135747.459013] PPP Deflate Compression module registered
```

No mention of a device being created. `syslog` seems to be more useful:

```
Apr 26 13:52:15 server pppd[12725]: pppd 2.4.5 started by muru, uid 0
Apr 26 13:52:15 server pppd[12725]: Using interface ppp0
Apr 26 13:52:15 server pppd[12725]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/7
Apr 26 13:52:15 server pppd[12725]: BSD-Compress (15) compression enabled
```

The `Using interface ppp0` line seems to be what I want. I think I can get it thus:

```
awk '/started by muru/{getline; pppdev=$NF} END {print pppdev}'
```

Can I rely on the output of pppd for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d` is the location you are looking for.

My example is valid on Gentoo Linux but the same directory structure seems to exist on Arch.

Every time a VPN connection is made `/etc/ppp/ip-up` is run, which typically executes `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/*` in turn. Its first argument is the attached `pppn` device.

Put this script under `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/90-local` for instance:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Optional trace:
# logger -t "ppp" "$6: $1 (${2:--}, $3) $4 --> $5"

iptables -A FORWARD -i $1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o $1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

You might as well use the environment variables `pppd` sets before running scripts. The one you are looking for is `$DEVICE`. Simply replace `$1` with `$DEVICE` in the above script:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i $DEVICE -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o $DEVICE -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

See `man pppd` for more info on what `pppd` does when establishing a connection.

Comment: Correction: The server is Ubuntu, the client is Arch. But yes, I checked and the same directory structure is present on the server. And it works beautifully.

Comment: @muru Glad it works. It would make more sense to add `-i $DEVICE` to `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`. Without it you can just make it a permanent rule... IIF *all* traffic going through `eth0` *must* be masqueraded.